# Is it legal to turn off ADS-B before landing and only after takeoff in Europe (GA)?

Tags: general-aviation

I noticed in https://globe.adsbexchange.com that all aircraft of a certain company do not show ADS-B signal on almost all take offs and landings (around 3000-4000 feet) over the past 6 months.

Assuming that it is company policy and not a signal issue, would this be legal? i.e. what are the specific requirements regarding the point during the trip that the ADS-B is expected to be turned on.

If relevant, they are using mostly Cessna 650 Citation (C650), operating in DE,UK,DK,etc.

Comment: What company? Tail numbers?

Comment: That sounds pretty unlikely. More likely, the hobby website you are talking about does not have perfect coverage, so it will lose tracking of certain aircraft below certain altitudes in certain areas.

Comment: @60levelchange, you are right, I phrased the question under a set of assumptions that are not necessarily true. I re-phrased the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen at Mumbai airport too and I can confirm it's related to certain plane models and their specific transponder characteristics. They aren't turning off ADS-B but instead, the ADS-B coverage for those planes is poor. I've noticed that when this happens (on FR24 at least) you can track the planes using MLAT.

I'm quite sure it's not the pilots actually doing anything with the transponders, the altitudes you've mentioned are also pretty similar to what I've noticed a rare few times at Mumbai airport.

I had posted this exact same question a few months ago but it got downvoted and I had to remove it.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't make much sense to me that you'd be able to track it with MLAT if it was still broadcasting ADSB - you only need one receiver to detect ADSB because all the data you need is in the packet whereas you need several for MLAT

Comment: @Dan, didn't get you.

Comment: This answer does not make sense. If you can track an aircraft with MLAT, it means you are receiving messages from the transponder at multiple receivers simultaneously. This means that the coverage must be good. If the some of those message would be ADS-B messages, they would be received as well. So you can't have poor ADS-B coverage and do MLAT at the same time. If you can do MLAT, you can also receive ADS-B messages, unless the aircraft isn't broadcasting any.

Comment: @DeltaLima I do not know, it happens with certain aircraft but most aircraft are not affected by this poor ADS-B coverage